# Get the cursor (caret) position in an editable JComboBox in Netbeans GUI Builder

Tags: netbeans, jcombobox, caret

In a JTextField I can find the caret position with

```
int caretPos = textField.getCaretPosition();
```

and can obviously set it with: setCaretPosition()

I'm listening for [keyTyped](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyTyped-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-) on both JTextField and JComboBox (editable) so I can filter out non-numeric characters - [InputEvent.consume()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume--).

But getCaretPosition() method isn't supplied by JComboBox. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Netbeans then you'll have noticed that using the GUI Builder Events just doesn't work for a combo box; because a combo box is a compound component. So you must have done something like this if you're listening for keyTyped events:

```
jCombo.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
        //do stuff!
    }
});
```

I suspect you have an idea that casting getEditorComponent() to JTextField must be the answer, and it is; here's the syntax, note the brackets.

```
caretPos = ( (JTextField)jCombo.getEditor().getEditorComponent() ).getCaretPosition();
```